# Connecting a MySQL database to a javaApp using Sockets

Tags: java, mysql, database, javafx, serversocket

I am trying to create an "online" paying system for desktop, using Java Eclipse ( JavaFX, MySQL). The idea is that a client(or provider) can log In/Register to the app and then he can pay bills(client) or create them(provider). 
I did all the connection to the database, but it's local and as I understand for better function of the program I should use Sockets/ServerSockets to establish a connection between the database and the user(may it be a client/provider).
I tried and searched and I'm still searching for a code that can help me understand how this connection could work.
Thus, I am asking for an example of a connection between the main program and a database using a ServerSocket/Socket , where the Client class has:

```
public class Client extends User{
private String ID_card, name, surname;
private double founds;

public Client(int id, String userName, String password, String email, String ID_card, double founds, String name, String surname) {
    super(id, userName, password, email);
    this.ID_card = ID_card;
    this.founds = founds;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;

}
```

Also, if possible, I would truly appreciate an example of adding a client to the database using the ServerSocket/Socket. (even a link is perfect)
This is my addClient method for the local database (disc makes the difference between a client and a provider)

```
public void addClient(Client client) {
    try {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
                "insert into users(username,password,email,ID_card,name,surname,disc) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, client.getUserName());
        ps.setString(2, client.getPassword());
        ps.setString(3, client.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4, client.getID_card());
        ps.setString(5, client.getName());
        ps.setString(6, client.getSurname());
        ps.setString(7, "client");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()) {
            client.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        }
        closeConnection(conn);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken you are trying to write a mysql driver! You will be delighted to know there are several already written

Comment: @e4c5 there may be... but my teacher was very precise when he said that he wants us to build everything from scratch... using sockets and all that. It's my first big app... and i am really trying...

Comment: Either your teacher is nuts or you have misunderstood. Creating a JDBC driver is not a class room project.

Comment: I may have... he didn't said anything clearly. He just said that we should use ServerSockets in our app, to send data to the socket which then will process it, and send it back. Like LogIn, for example. I put the username&password in the TextField, by clicking the button it goes to the server which searches if there is any user with those in the database. If yes, the main window opens , if it doesn't, a message pops up...